# How can I use the MySQL record id to name an image?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that saves the signature from html5 canvas and assigns a random number as the image name then stores it in a folder and posts the name in MySQL.

I already have a record in the MySQL table that will be associated with this image, when that record is edited to include this image I want to save the image with the EXISTING record id.

So basically the script saves the images like this  sign_4354533225533.png  I want to remove the number generator and replace it with the record id, Meaning, the browser will pass the record id of 42 to signature_pad.php I want to take that id and use it to name my file so it would look like sign_42.png.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
//$session_id = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// Get the data
$imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
// Remove the headers (data:,) part.
// A real application should use them according to needs such as to check image type
$filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

// Need to decode before saving since the data we received is already base64 encoded
$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

//echo "unencodedData".$unencodedData;
$sig_name = "sign_" . rand(5,1000) . rand(1, 10) . rand(10000, 150000) . rand(1500, 100000000) . ".png";
//Set the absolute path to your folder (i.e. /usr/home/your-domain/your-folder/
$filepath = "/xampp/htdocs/alpha/development/final/uploads/signatures/" . $sig_name;
$customer_signature=$_POST['customer_signature'];
$fp = fopen("$filepath", 'wb' );
fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
fclose( $fp );

//Connect to a mySQL database and store the user's information so you can link to it later
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root', 'pwd') OR DIE(mysql_error);
mysql_select_db("customer", $link);
mysql_query("UPDATE signature SET customer_signature=$customer_signature WHERE 'id'= '$id'"); OR DIE(mysql_error());
mysql_close($link);
}
?>
 <?php
session_start()
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
 <head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Signature Pad</title>

<!-- The Signature Pad -->
< script type ="text/javascript"    src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="signature-pad.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<fieldset style="width: 435px">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="signaturePad" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; height: 55px; width: 400px;"></div>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <button id="clearSig" type="button">Clear Signature</button>&nbsp;
    <button id="saveSig" type="button">Save Signature</button>
    <div id="imgData"></div>
    <br/>
    </fieldset>
</center>
<!--<div id="debug"></div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: move the image save code below the insert and use `mysql_insert_id` to get the file base name

Comment: @Orangepill that didn't work, now it doesn't do anything, wont upload the file to the folder or post to MySQL. There is already a record id in MySQL for the customer, I just want to grab it like you would when you pass the id from page to page and insert that as the name.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT TO ACCOMODATE YOUR ABOVE CHANGES**

So with your $id = $_GET['id'];
Just grab the row from the database...

```
 $id=$_GET['id'];
 $customer_signature=$_POST['customer_signature']; 

 $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM signature WHERE id ='$id'");
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);

 //THEN SAVE IMAGE with the fetched row ID ($row['id'])
 $filepath = "/xampp/htdocs/alpha/development/final/uploads/signatures/".$row['id'];
 $fp = fopen("$filepath", 'wb' );
 fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
 fclose( $fp );


 //THEN WHEN YOU SAVE IT BACK ITS AN UPDATE
 mysql_query("UPDATE signature SET 'customer_signature'='".$_POST['customer_signature']."', 'sig_name'=$sig_name" WHERE id = ".$id);
```

BUT...**WARNING**

You really should not be using the deprecated mysql_* functions.
Instead google PDO, learn it, and use that instead :)

Comment: I'm going to rephrase the question above I already have a record id I don't want to create a new one

Comment: How can you possibly have a record id, if youre doing an INSERT.  An INSERT is a NEW RECORD by default.  If you have one already, then you should be doing an UPDATE.....or doing an INSERT with an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: @KyleK Ok I understand all that, but for the moment I'm working on just getting the name to save as the id passed in the browser. I'm not concerned with anything else but that.

Comment: Well, I think I got the answer for you above :)

Comment: @KyleK isn't there a way to grab the id that's passed in the browser and use that? just like I do this 'signature_pad.php?=<?php echo $id=$_GET['id'] ?>', to the button that proceeds to the next page?

Comment: Your original question said you wanted to name the image as the id....that was all.. so you needed to get it from the table....I answered you, to do that....then you say you have it already.....being passed....so I cahnge to update to include that....what is the problem now....I really dont understand

Comment: What do you actually want to do??? Save the filepath of the image in the database?  Save the image with the id?  Save the ACTUAL image into the db?? what?????

Comment: @KyleK look I appreciate the help but don't patronize me, I know exactly what I want if you would READ the question I said I WANT TO USE THE RECORD ID TO SAVE THE IMAGE INSTEAD OF THE RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR THAT IS IN PLACE! so I'm pretty sure my issue lies in this section of code $sig_name = "sign_" . rand(5,1000) . rand(1, 10) . rand(10000, 150000) . rand(1500, 100000000) . ".png";
since this is where the file is named.

Comment: Ive really read it 20 times already, I still don't get what you want...Im not patronizing you, Im just frustrated because Im spending time on this, but you're not helping me by not being very clear...in other words.....help me...help you

Comment: You say "I want to save the image as the record id passed by the browser"........but while thats clear to you, because you know what you want....that can mean multiple differenet things to me.  It could mean... save it LITERALLY as the id as the filename?  Save it in the database with that id, as a path to the file??....save the ACTUAL file as a blob into the db under that id??....see what I mean

Comment: @KyleK ok look, the script generates a random number and names the image something like this sign_32345332884885948.png  I want to remove the number generator and but the record id in it's place. so if the browser has passed record 42 to the signature_pad.php then I want to save the image as sign_42.png   that's all I don't care about posting it in MySQL it will be saved in a folder as that name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31563/discussion-between-kylek-and-user2447848)